# Jquery- How to set the date before today can't be select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, jquery-ui-datepicker

I able to make today date appear at the check-in date, but the problem is the user still be able to choose the date before today date. Is that any solution can allow me to solve his problem? Any suggestion will be a great help, thanks !

```
$(function () {
        $("#chkI").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", showAnim: "slideDown", 
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                var newMin = new Date(minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 1));
                $("#chkO").datepicker("option", "minDate", newMin);
            }
        });
        var currentDate = new Date();
        $("#chkI").datepicker("setDate", currentDate);
        $("#chkO").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", showAnim: "slideDown",
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                var maxDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                var newMax = new Date(maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate() - 1));
                $("#chkI").datepicker("option", "maxDate", newMax);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I disable dates before today :

```
$("#chkI").datepicker({
    minDate: new Date()
});
```

e.g. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nfa3ydjh/)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set minDate and don't initialize datepicker again for same input

```js
$(function () {
            $("#chkI").datepicker({
                minDate: new Date(), // start date should be today's date
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", showAnim: "slideDown", 
                onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                    var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                    var newMin = new Date(minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 1));
                    $("#chkO").datepicker("option", "minDate", newMin);
                }
            }).datepicker("setDate", new Date()); // select today's date by default
            //var currentDate = new Date();
            //$("#chkI").datepicker("setDate", currentDate);
            $("#chkO").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", showAnim: "slideDown",
                onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                    var maxDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                    var newMax = new Date(maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate() - 1));
                    $("#chkI").datepicker("option", "maxDate", newMax);
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="chkI">
<input type="text" id="chk0">
```

Comment: I still able to select the date before today in check-in there

Comment: @J.Boy there is a property `minDate`, which can be used to disable dates before today, try my solution!